# GCP Cloud Run Cloud - Cloud SQL instance "${process.env.INSTANCE_CONNECTION_NAME}" is not reachable

Tags: postgresql, google-cloud-sql, google-cloud-run

I am getting the above error when trying to connect to a cloud sql instance that is sitting in another project. This then also throws the following error in the logs:

```
ENOENT /cloudsql/${process.env.INSTANCE_CONNECTION_NAME}/.s.PGSQL.5432
```

The connections in Cloud Run have been set up and points to the instance in the other project:

[Cloud run connections](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hlwau.png)

Additionally the service account used for this deployment has Cloud SQL Client permissions in both its own project and the one where the SQL instance is.

Finally the environmental variable is also set in cloud run and has the correct instance connection name.

I originally tried to get this working on an existing deployement with no luck and then also deployed it from scratch, but the same errors keep occuring.

The application is node.js based with sequelize as ORM.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: One thing to make sure is that you have the [Cloud SQL Admin API](https://console.cloud.google.com/apis/api/sqladmin.googleapis.com/) enabled within both Google Cloud projects.

Comment: @JackWotherspoon I had checked that too and the API is enabled in both projects

Comment: @nm_machine89 whats the cloud sql version you are using?

Comment: @nm_machine89 is the Cloud SQL instance setup for public or private IP?

Comment: @DivyaniYadav PostgreSQL 14

Comment: @JackWotherspoon it is set up for both public and private IPs

Comment: can you refer to this link : https://stackoverflow.com/a/60168207/15774176 is it helpful?

Comment: @DivyaniYadav deleting the instance would be a last resort as it holds production data. The cloud SQL instance is also definitely 2nd generation as the instance name has the project:region:name format.

Comment: I feel the issue with IP address can try these link [1]: https://stackoverflow.com/a/58141612/15774176
[2]: https://stackoverflow.com/a/67411472/15774176 and see is it helpful or not?

Comment: @DivyaniYadav sorry for the late response, using the Unix Socket is how I am trying to connect

Answer (score 0):

I've manged to solve this, the problem was in the config.js with the connection strings.

Intially the connection string was like:

```
username: process.env.DB_USER,
password: process.env.DB_PASS,
database: process.env.DB_NAME,
host: '/cloudsql/${process.env.INSTANCE_CONNECTION_NAME}',
dialect: 'postgres',
dialectOptions: {
  socketPath: '/cloudsql/${process.env.INSTANCE_CONNECTION_NAME}'
}
```

It seems that Cloud Run was not able to read the INSTANCE_CONNECTION_NAME. I changed this to:

```
username: process.env.DB_USER,
password: process.env.DB_PASS,
database: process.env.DB_NAME,
host: process.env.INSTANCE_CONNECTION_NAME,
dialect: 'postgres',
dialectOptions: {
  socketPath: process.env.INSTANCE_CONNECTION_NAME
}
```

and set the INSTANCE_CONNECTION_NAME to include the /cloudsql/ portion and voila it worked.